# Forkim's innerRef is updating every time a field in the form is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am new with formik and I have a very annoying problem that I am stuck on with days. So basically I have a parent component in which I have a code like this:

```
const refs=[]
{data.map((v,i) =>
<Child formikRef={refs}}/> )}
```

And my child component uses formik:

```
...
<Formik
innerRef={i => props.formikRef.push(i)}
....../>
```

So my Child component is rendered a couple of times in my parent component, and I need to track the values of each in my parent component. To be more clear, when I click on button that is located in my parent component, I need to have the values from each  (I need to pass data from child to parent component). That's why I am using innerRef. The problem is that I am using an array of refs to track values of each rendered , and a new value is added in the array every time I change a field in my form, so I have far more elements in my array than I should have. I think innderRef is triggered each time a change in a field is made, instead of only onSubmit. How I can solve this problem? Pls help.

Comment: You try like this this, const refs = React.useRef([])

{data.map((v,i) =>
 <Child key={i} formikRef={refs}/> 
)} 


<Formik
 innerRef={i => props.formikRef.current.push(i)}
/>

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Trick could be <Formik innerRef={i => props.formikRef.current[i]=i)} />, note that instead of Array.prototype.push have assignment on each index with value.

Comment: The problem here is that **i** here is an object so it is not working, I am having only the values of the last form. Instead of current[**i**] probably there is another way to set the index?

Answer (score 1):

You could try like below, Here we are passing index value to Child component to have Formik ref in the same place.

```
const refs=[]

{data.map((v,i) =>
    <Child index={i} formikRef={refs}}/> 
)} 

<Formik
    innerRef={props.formikRef[props.index]}
/>
```